# Howto check if control key is released

Tags: vb.net

I am searching how to detect if control key, and no other keys, is released (in textbox).
This is what I came up so far:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = 17 Then
        GetTick = System.Environment.TickCount
    End If
End Sub
```

This work's but triggers also in combination keys like Ctrl+c etc...
With what to replace 17?

Comment: You need to think this through a bit, your user can't release the keys at the *exact* same time.  The normal way to press Ctrl+C is Ctrl, then C, then release C, then release Ctrl.  So unless you keep history then there isn't a good way to tell that only the Ctrl key was pressed.

Comment: Hi Hans, question is clear. Detecting when (and only when) ctrl key was pressed (actually released) alone. If later someone accidentally press (say) C key then first condition goes to False.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried e.Control, as in the following:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
     If e.Control Then
        GetTick = System.Environment.TickCount
     End If
End Sub
```

Adapted from:
http://www.devcurry.com/2009/10/detecting-ctrl-and-shift-keys-on-form.html

Comment: Hi, I do try. This works (as boolean) on keyDown but not on keyUp handler.

Comment: Have you tried putting a MsgBox in KeyUp to ensure it is fired when Ctrl is pressed by itself?  If so, you can then display the fields of e to see what you need to check for.

Comment: Yes, keyUp event is fired as expected. That's how I came up to '17' :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used VB in a while but here's some stuff that might help you.
You can try creating a boolean variable (true false), called ctrl or something like that. Make it true when the control key is first pressed, then make it false when they put the key up. Then you could create another variable that stores all the key codes called keycodes or something. Make keycodes -1 when a key other than control is pressed. Here is some example code :

```
    Dim kys=-1
Dim ctrl=false
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    if e.KeyValue = Keys.Control then
        ctrl=false
    else
        kys=-1
    end if
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    if e.KeyValue = Keys.Control then
        ctrl=true
    else
        kys=e.getKeyValue
    end if
    'Control c
    if ctrl=true & kys=Keys.c then
        MsgBox("It Worked!")
    end if
End Sub
```

By the way, e.KeyValue is usually better than e.keyCode for stuff like this, it's easier to use because you can just use "Keys" instead of looking up all the keycodes.

Comment: Condition "if e.KeyValue = Keys.Control then" are never meet on my keyUp event...

Comment: Should be `Keys.ControlKey`

Comment: SSS, Yes it is! I can use a constant Keys.ControlKey instead of 17. Thank you.